How to recreate this "wet flame" effect coming out of an object?
I only finished the donut tutorial and playing around with some models, so I'm pretty much a noob, please bare with me.
Is it possible to recreate this kind of effect on an object? To me it looks like it's mirroring the object, but it's applying some effect that I can only describe as water + flames moving upwards. I managed to play around and make something with a Noise Texture node but it looks very flat in comparison, it doesn't 'come out' of the model and it's merely a texture on top of the model, not mirroring it at all.
Pic for reference:

Any tips on how to recreate something like this or tutorials that I should watch?
Thanks!
Link to video example
